# SQL scenario to group a dimension

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, group-by

I am using SQL and here is the scenario I am stuck with

```
Table A
SubscriptionID | Club   | Sum_Of_Billings_Of_All_Month | EventID  


Table B:
Cost           | EventID
```

`Table A left join Table B on EventID` (To track the cost of each subscription)

**Result**

```
SubscriptionID | Club   | Sum_Of_Billings_Of_All_Month  | EventID  | Cost
```

I want to break down the `Sum_Of_Billings_Of_All_Month` into per day billings. i.e. for each subscription, I want the breakdown of billings per day of the month. For that I will `group by` `Sum_Of_Billings_Of_All_Month` instead of `subscriptionID`.

**Consequence**

If I group by days of billing, upon joining I will get duplicates of `subscriptionIDs` and the `eventIDs` will be duplicated in rows multiple time which will then count the cost multiple times as well.

**What I want:**

- In the same query, I want to be able to group by `SubscriptionID` so I can keep the unique subscriptions per row with their cost.
- But one of the other requirement is that I want to know the breakdown of the billings as well to calculate the breakeven and other metrics in the same query

**Here is the actual sample data**

**Table A**

```
idCustomerSubscription  | ClubID  |     EventId     |   BillingDate|    FinalRevenue
33562784                | 56180001| 5y6m600np1fg    |   5/31/2017  |    512
```

**Table B**

```
EventId         |Cost
5y6m600np1fg    |200
```

**Table A join B left join on eventId (Group by SubscriptionID**

```
idCustomerSubscription  |ClubID      |EventId     |BillingDate| FinalRevenue    | Cost  
33562784                | 56180001   |5y6m600np1fg| 5/31/2017 | 512      |200
```

It serves the purpose because each subscription has one cost which is unique BUT it on the other hand, this kind of query will not give me breakdown of dates of billings (I need it for the breakeven calculation)

**Table A join B left join on eventId (Group by billingdate**

```
idCustomerSubscription| ClubID  |EventId            |   BillingDate|    FinalRevenue    |Cost   
33562784              | 56180001|   5y6m600np1fg    |5/30/2017           |510           |200    
33562784              | 56180001|   5y6m600np1fg    |5/31/2017             |2               |200
```

This would give me the breakdown of the dates which i need for breakeven (510 on 30th and 2 on 31st) but it will make the cost duplicated (400 is the cost instead of 200)

---

I want to find out a SQL magic where I can keep the number of unique subcriptions per row and some way to track the billing dates of each subscriptions in the same query (without grouping it by date because it will make the rows duplicated). Is it possible ?

Perhaps some way where when the eventids are joined and its grouped by date, it doesnt duplicate the cost and count only one cost per eventid?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: you said, you want to break down the Sum_Of_Billings_Of_All_Month into per day billings. So do you want to follow calendar days for each month or just standard 30. It will be easy to understand you if you have given some more examples

Comment: updated the question with sample

Comment: what is your desired output from above result set??

Comment: I want to find out a SQL magic where I can keep the number of unique subcriptions per row and some way to track the billing dates of each subscriptions in the same query (without grouping it by date because it will make the rows duplicated).

Comment: it is very easy if you provide sample output rather than repeating the requirement

Comment: sample output would have cost not repeated for the same subscription

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will get your desired result with below query. Try to modify your group by operation for mn (alias name) table.

```
select mn.idCustomerSubscription,mn.ClubID,mn.EventId,mn.BillingDate,mn.FinalRevenue,sq.cost
     from tableA Mn left join (select idCustomerSubscription,max(cost) cost, min(billingDate) billingDate from tableA a left join tableB b on a.eventid=b.eventid group by idCustomerSubscription) sq on mn.idCustomerSubscription=sq.idCustomerSubscription and mn.billingDate=sq.billingdate
group by mn.idCustomerSubscription,mn.ClubID,mn.EventId,mn.BillingDate
```

Comment: @pythondev once check my answer and let me know any issues